# How can i get the instance of a BackgroundWorker from the currently executed method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am using a backgroundworker that can have n instances.  Problem is the DoWork method (that has the 'sender' parameter which is the BackgroundWorker) calls other code that produces a callback - thus i dont have the sender.

How can i determine the BackgroundWorker that the current code is running under?

ex:

```
private void SetupThread()
{
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoTheWork);
}


private void DoTheWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{

    // I know that sender here can be converted, but thats no good for me
    MyClass.DoSomething(); // This will produce a callback(event) from MyClass
}

private void MethodCalledFromEventCallback()
{
   // Here is where the actual work is being done.  I need to determine which
   // instance of the Backgroundworker is calling it so that i can use the         
   // UpdateProgress method

  // I cannot do this :-(  (BackgroundWorker)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread;

}
```

Im probably just overlooking something (unless threadpool is in order :-( )

Im sure this is easily doable with the BackgroundWorker ... any ideas?

---

### edit

I caused some confusion in my description, here are some more facts :-)
1.)  I already call the bw.RunWorkerAsync() 
2.)  The class that invokes the event MethodCalledFromEventCallback has no knowledge of the background thread
3.)  I cannot (due to design requirements) include the Backgroundworker as a parameter

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the best you could probably get away with using a background worker is (assuming the constrants you've mentioned so far):

```
private void SetupThread()
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    // Assuming you need sender and e. If not, you can just send bw
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(DoTheWork);
}

private void DoTheWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    MyClass.Callback = () => 
        {
            ((BackgroundWorker)bw).UpdateProgress(/*send your update here*/);
            MethodCalledFromEventCallback();
        };

    MyClass.DoSomething(); // This will produce a callback(event) from MyClass
}

private void MethodCalledFromEventCallback() 
{ 
    // You've already sent an update by this point, so no background parameter required
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(bw);
```

Comment: The final block that actually performs the work is from an event of a class, it has no knowledge of the BackgrounWorker :-(

Answer (score 1):

Could you just send the "sender" along as a parameter to the callback, and get at the BGW that way?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [RunWorkerAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f00zz5b2.aspx) method that takes an argument, which is then available as the [Argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.argument.aspx) property of the event parameter.

You could then pass the BackgroundWorker instance to the background method.

Answer (score 1):

Your design requirements need a bit of work. A method that *must* use `BackgroundWorker.UpdateProgress` can't take the `BackgroundWorker` as a parameter? You *could* modify Gordon's answer to take a delegate instead, I suppose.

If you want this kind of separation of concerns, then you'll probably be a lot happier using the `Task` library in 4.0. They separate the work to be done (the "update" code) from the scheduling of that work.